# Run Tizen SmartTV App without internet access

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, offline-mode, tizen-web-app

I am currently developing an application for a SmartTV using the **Tizen SDK**, and when I try to run my application without internet access I get the following error:

> **You're not connected to the internet. This feature requires internet access WAS0003**

My simple **config.xml** has the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns:tizen="http://tizen.org/ns/widgets" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" id="http://sssss" version="1.0.0" viewmodes="maximized">
    <tizen:application id="srJXNxHxpd.Basicapplication" package="srJXNxHxpd" required_version="2.4"/>
    <content src="index.html"/>
    <icon src="icon.png"/>
    <name>xxx</name>
    <tizen:profile name="tv"/>
    <tizen:setting screen-orientation="portrait" context-menu="enable" background-support="disable" encryption="disable" install-location="auto" hwkey-event="enable"/>
</widget>
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Check your privilidge in tizen-manifest.xml.

Comment: My config.xml (== to the tizen-manifest.xml) is above and it has no privileges.

Answer (score 4):

Please add below privilege and policy in your `config.xml` as it's required if your application needs internet connection.

```
<tizen:privilege name="tizen.org/privilege/internet"/>
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
```

By adding privilege, it allows the application to access the Internet. This privilege is for both native and Web application.

By `<access>` element in `config.xml` Developers can specify protocols, domains, and sub-domains.

> If your application doesn't need any kind of internet access, you don't need to add these. But if your application  needs any kind of internet access, you need to add these. Please check your features again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this help, but try add following line to your `config.xml`

```
<tizen:metadata key="http://samsung.com/tv/metadata/use.network" value="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the “http://samsung.com/tv/metadata/use.network” metadata key to "false"

The “http://samsung.com/tv/metadata/use.network” key enables or disables checking the network connection when the application is launched.

[source](https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/guides/fundamentals/configuring-tv-applications.html)